# regexp maximal length restrict

Tags: regex

I have some regular expression like that:

```
(\d+\.)+
```

it's implement strings like 1.234.2421.222.11
Can i restrict max length of whole string (not quantity of groups)?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Note that `(\d+\.)+` does not match `1.234.2421.222.11` in it's entire. Your pattern mandates it should end with a `.`. You probably want a pattern like this:

```
\d+(\.\d+)*
```

And to give the input string a max length, say a max of 15 chars, do something like this:

```
^(?=.{0,15}$)\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

assuming your regex implementation supports look aheads.

### EDIT

Okay, if your regex implementation does not support look aheads, do it in two steps. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
if input matches ^\d+(\.\d+)*$ and ^.{0,15}$ do
  ....
end
```

or, as paxdiablo also mentioned, use your programming language's built-in function to get the length of the string.

Comment: i see about last dot, it's a template for real time input checking, i cannot restrict last dot :)

Comment: Thanks and sorry, i using regexp with delphi library, this syntax isn't supported. may be you know, how to make logical "and" operation with regexp?

Comment: @ Nick There is no such thing as a logical AND in regex, you can mimic a logical AND by using lookaheads `(?=)`. what seems to be not supported, then I think you need to go for 2 regexes

Answer (score 4):

If your regex engine supports lookaheads, you can use something like:

```
^(?=.{M,N}$)(\d+\.)*\d+$
```

(fixed to not require a trailing `.` character) and this embeds the length check within the same regex. You need to replace `M` and `N` with the minimum and maximum size respectively.

If your engine is not so modern as to have lookaheads, you need to do *two* regex chacks:

```
^.{M,N}$
^(\d+\.)*\d+$
```

and ensure it passes them *both.* The first is the length check, the second is the content check.

But you may find that a regex is overkill for the length check, it's probably easier just to check the string length with `Length()`.