# Regex Java Total String Length

Tags: java, regex, expression, limit

I need the below regex to select only those of total size X:

```
[[JN]*P?[JN]*]N
```

EDIT:

e.g. for 6:

- JJPNNN -> JJPNNN
- ONNJNNNO -> NNJNNN
- NPJNJNN -> NPJNJN, PJNJNN
- NPJNN -> False

I need it to capture the group.

Comment: Will this work? `([[JN]*P?[JN]*]N){6}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regexp maximal length restrict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503177/regexp-maximal-length-restrict)

Comment: @BuhakeSindi No, it won't. that will repeat the whole pattern 6 times...

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead to first check the length, like this:

```
(?=^.{6}$)[[JN]*P?[JN]*]N
```

Also, you seem to have too many brackets. To make the expression match your examples, you need to remove the outermost one:

```
(?=^.{6}$)[JN]*P?[JN]*N
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/ZfIDsE) is a small demo using ideone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size limiting

```
\{5,10}
```

something like that limits a size of 5~10

You should look up on it, there is tons of answered questions about this topic

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "123456"
if(test.match("^\w{6,6}$")
{
  //True if String has length of 6
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a regex that will return true if it fits the pattern of `[JN]*P?[JN]*]N` **and** has a length of 6. Not one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {


    private static boolean match(String line) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?=[JNP]{6}$)[JN]*P?[JN]*N$");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
      return m.matches();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(match("JJPN"));
      System.out.println(match("JJPNNN"));
      System.out.println(match("NNJNNN"));
      System.out.println(match("NPJNJNN"));
      System.out.println(match("NPJNJNNNN"));

    }
}
```

out

```
false
true
true
false
false
```